# What happens if you kill the Brotherhood before meeting Veronica?

Tags: fallout-new-vegas

Veronica is an awesome companion and in my current save i've killed everyone in the BoH because of an accident involving a ranger outfit and the phrase "you came to the wrong neighborhood motherfucker". Am i screwed? or can i still get veronica?

Answer (score 3):

Depends on what the resulting [reputation](http://www.falloutwiki.com/Fallout:_New_Vegas_reputations) with the Brotherhood of Steel was.

From [The Vault wiki's "Veronica Santangelo" article](http://www.falloutwiki.com/Veronica_Santangelo#Effects_of_player_actions):

> Veronica will leave you if your reputation with the Brotherhood of Steel drops to Vilified. However, it seems that with a reputation even
>   as low as Merciful Thug, she will continue to happily accompany you on
>   your travels. It should be noted that she will remain a companion upon
>   destruction of the Hidden Valley bunker, although she warns it is your
>   last chance, similar to what happens with Craig Boone if you work too
>   closely with the Legion, or Rose of Sharon Cassidy if you gain
>   negative Karma while she is your companion.

Other player actions that may affect whether Veronica joins you or not:

> - If you talk negatively about the Brotherhood in your first conversation, she won't join you.
> - If you have destroyed the Brotherhood Bunker in Hidden Valley before recruiting her, she will come up to you and ask you what you know
>     about the Brotherhood at 188 trading post. If you tell her what you
>     did, she will say "Well in that case: This is for them." and attack
>     the player.